# Openlayers.js error on wildfly 16 only and not on GlassFish

Tags: javascript, glassfish, wildfly, openlayers

A project was migrated from GlassFish to wildfly 16, uses JDK8, and uses Openlayers.js.

After this migration, an error appears in the Openlayers.js code, `Uncaught TypeError: handler is not a constructor`, in the Draw drawing function, in this call: `this.handler = new handler(this, this.callbacks, this.handlerOptions );`

```
OpenLayers.Control.DrawFeature = OpenLayers.Class(OpenLayers.Control, {
layer: null,
callbacks: null,
EVENT_TYPES: ["featureadded"],
multi: false,
featureAdded: function() {},
handlerOptions: null,
initialize: function(layer, handler, options) {
    this.EVENT_TYPES = OpenLayers.Control.DrawFeature.prototype.EVENT_TYPES.concat(OpenLayers.Control.prototype.EVENT_TYPES);
    OpenLayers.Control.prototype.initialize.apply(this, [options]);
    this.callbacks = OpenLayers.Util.extend({
        done: this.drawFeature,
        modify: function(vertex, feature) {
            this.layer.events.triggerEvent("sketchmodified", {
                vertex: vertex,
                feature: feature
            });
        },
        create: function(vertex, feature) {
            this.layer.events.triggerEvent("sketchstarted", {
                vertex: vertex,
                feature: feature
            });
        }
    }, this.callbacks);
    this.layer = layer;
    this.handlerOptions = this.handlerOptions || {};
    if (!("multi"in this.handlerOptions)) {
        this.handlerOptions.multi = this.multi;
    }
    var sketchStyle = this.layer.styleMap && this.layer.styleMap.styles.temporary;
    if (sketchStyle) {
        this.handlerOptions.layerOptions = OpenLayers.Util.applyDefaults(this.handlerOptions.layerOptions, {
            styleMap: new OpenLayers.StyleMap({
                "default": sketchStyle
            })
        });
    }
    this.handler = new handler(this,this.callbacks,this.handlerOptions);
},
```

,

Thanks